# Make Absolute position scrollable on mobile

Tags: html, css

I have Absolute position for ul:

```
 `<ul class="dropdown-menu nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
            <li> Item #1 </li>
            <li> Item #1 </li>
            <li> Item #2 </li>
            <li> Item #3 </li>
               ...
        </ul>`
```

And here's my CSS

```
`.dropdown-menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
    float: left;
    min-width: 160px;
    list-style: none;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
}`
```

So it works perfect as i want for the desktop ... But for mobile phones with less than 320px width (like iPhone 5) The list of Items is so long, that there's not enough height. So i would like to make it scrollable, but still keep absolute... Is it possible? 
I tried to add new `div` with `position:relative` but it didn't work...

Comment: You need to wrap the menu into an absolutely positioned div set to `overflow: scroll`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
overflow-x: hidden;
height: auto;
max-height:400 px;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.